# Error while taking an screenshot with js

Tags: javascript, html

I have a web page and I need a button where this takes a screenshot of the screen. Right now, I have the following js function that is excecuted by a button on html:

```
var takeScreenShot = function() {
    html2canvas(document.getElementById("container"), {
        onrendered: function (canvas) {
            var tempcanvas=document.createElement('canvas');
            tempcanvas.width=550;
            tempcanvas.height=650;
            var context=tempcanvas.getContext('2d');
            context.drawImage(canvas,0,0,tempcanvas.width,tempcanvas.height,0,0,tempcanvas.width,tempcanvas.height);
            var link=document.createElement("a");
            link.href=tempcanvas.toDataURL('image/jpg');
            link.download = 'screenshot.jpg';
            link.click();
        }
    });
}
```

Then, the html has the following:

```
<div style="margin-right: 100px; margin-left: 600px" id="container">
  <table class="myTable">
    <th class="titles">Title</th>
    <!-- code code code -->
    <button onclick="takeScreenShot()">Table Screenshot</button>
  </table>
</div>
```

This works but the problem is that the screen taken come with errors. The next image is how is taking the screenshot:

[Screenshot taken with the button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wkbwj.png)

And this is how it should be.

[Screenshot taken manually](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PARw4.png)

Comment: What if you try give it `png` extension `tempcanvas.toDataURL('image/png')` and `screenshot.png`

Comment: I've tried this but still the same.